# Netty ReadTimeoutHandler triggering multiple timeouts

Tags: netty

It looks like the default behavior of `ReadTimeoutHandler` is to spam `ReadTimeoutException`s upstream until the shared timer object is destroyed or the channel is destroyed. The problem is, it manages to fire off multiple `ReadTimeoutException`s before the channel closes.

Is this to be expected or am I doing something wrong?

What's the most Netty-idiomatic way of making it emit only one `ReadTimeoutException`? Should I just write a channel handler that only passes the first `ReadTimeoutException` it sees upstream?

Comment: Which netty version ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your requirement is one request one timeout?

You could change a little bit of the ReadTimeoutHandler, 1. After request sendout, create a timeOut task  2. once a timeOut happened, you could cancel the timeout task.